# Welche Wortart sind Zahlwörter

Tags: numbers, word-classes

Zum Beispiel "vier Menschen" oder "ein Wort". Ist "vier"/"ein" ein Artikel, oder eine andere Wortart?
Und ist ein Zahlwort allein wie "Eins, Zwei, Drei" ein Nomen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diese Frage ist nicht so einfach zu beantworten. Denn wie viele und welche Wortarten man unterscheidet, ist nicht eindeutig und endgültig festgelegt. Tatsächlich gibt es immer wieder neue Vorschläge, die oft kontrovers diskutiert werden. Der [Wikipedia-Artikel zu Wortarten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortart) gibt einen Eindruck.

Entsprechend gibt es auch unterschiedliche Meinungen, welche Wortart Zahlwörter sein sollen. Manchmal werden mindestens die [Grundzahlwörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahlwort#Kardinalia) als Adjektive betrachtet. Es gibt aber auch die Auffassung, sie gemeinsam mit anderen Wörtern, die etwas mit Zahlen zu tun haben, in eine eigene Wortart zu packen. Das sind dann die [Zahlwörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahlwort) oder Numerale. Welche Wörter mit Bezug auf Zahlen genau zu den Numeralen gehören, ist auch wieder umstritten. Je nachdem, an welchem System und welcher Einteilung der Wortarten man sich orientiert, wird man eine dieser Varianten oder noch ganz andere finden.

Es gibt übrigens tatsächlich Substantive zu den Grundzahlwörtern. Das ist dann aber nicht etwas wie "vier Menschen", sondern eher "eine Vier würfeln" oder "die Note Vier".